# I want Cell B to reflect a number depending on what I choose in drop down A

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

CellA1 has a drop down I created that will show either text "Full Time" or "Part Time"

I want Cell B1 to reflect it accordingly:

Full Time = 30
Part Time = 20

Comment: What kind of drop-down is it?

Comment: The kind where you click on data validation and choose list, does that answer your question? That's the only one I know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1)="F",30,20)
```

Comment: Uh I feel so stupid for not figuring that out, i need to start reading excel for dummies - its simple stuff like a comma between 30,20 that I get stumped

Comment: Tsk, Tsk. I will try to use better gramma in the future and watch my spelling and punctuations.